# Apache: Avoiding multiple redirect rule sets within .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

We currently have a url structure of https://www.ourdomain.com/index.php/category/page.html (messy I know)

I have generated two rules in htaccess to remove the index.php and the .html suffix. What is happening is when trying to go to an old page URL there are two redirects happening to give the new URL and i only want a single redirect due to google rank.

```
#remove index.php on all but blogs and prs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/prs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blogs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/complaints/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/feedback/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ncr/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index.php/?([^\ \?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=301,L]

#redirect non.html to page.html to avoid duplicate content
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/prs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blogs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/complaints/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/feedback/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ncr/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Is there any way to do this with a single redirect?

In response to the first comment here is what happens when old url is entered:

```
>>> https://www.ourdomain.com/index.php/chair-hire.html

> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------
Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Date:   Fri, 15 Dec 2017 15:00:15 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=ddd3f35a3882ef9246f5264eadf0cf4b11513350015; expires=Sat, 15-Dec-18 15:00:15 GMT; path=/; domain=.ourdomain.com; HttpOnly
Accept-Ranges:  bytes
Location:   https://www.ourdomain.com/chair-hire.html
Cache-Control:  public,public
X-Turbo-Charged-By: LiteSpeed
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 3cda457ea87706fa-LHR



>>> https://www.ourdomain.com/chair-hire.html

> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------
Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Date:   Fri, 15 Dec 2017 15:00:16 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d9c2093f3e27ea26759390fdef33592941513350016; expires=Sat, 15-Dec-18 15:00:16 GMT; path=/; domain=.ourdomain.com; HttpOnly
Accept-Ranges:  bytes
Location:   https://www.ourdomain.com/chair-hire
Cache-Control:  public,public
X-Turbo-Charged-By: LiteSpeed
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 3cda457fe91606fa-LHR



>>> https://www.ourdomain.com/chair-hire

> --------------------------------------------
> 200 OK
> --------------------------------------------
Status: 200 OK
Code:   200
Date:   Fri, 15 Dec 2017 15:00:17 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: e8f92725fb25bc53c7c879dc66fb73b9=nvvkhf9aahks9qa2f7njhnphm7; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
P3P:    CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Cache-Control:  no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Expires:    Mon, 1 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified:  Fri, 15 Dec 2017 15:00:16 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
X-Litespeed-Cache:  miss
Vary:   Accept-Encoding
X-Turbo-Charged-By: LiteSpeed
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 3cda4580cb1c0b81-LHR
```

Comment: There IS a way. I'm thinking along the lines of the `(\.html|)` OR like matching. But I'm failing to come up with something concrete. Just have to wait for one of them Rewrite wizards to show up ;) In the meantime, do you have multiple full URL examples that may exist that should match, and their rewritten result?